# Node.JS encrypt using MD5 / ECB and padding w/PKCS7

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I inherited a database that has the passwords utilizing the following functions to encrypt/decrypt in VB.NET

```
Public Shared Function EncryptString(ByVal Message As String, ByVal Passphrase As String) As String
        Dim Results As Byte()
        Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        Dim HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim TDESKey As Byte() = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase))
        Dim TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        Dim DataToEncrypt As Byte() = UTF8.GetBytes(Message)
        Dim Encryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor()
        Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(Results)
    End Function


    Public Shared Function DecryptString(ByVal Message As String, ByVal Passphrase As String) As String
        Dim Results As Byte()
        Dim UTF8 As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        Dim HashProvider As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim TDESKey As Byte() = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase))
        Dim TDESAlgorithm As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        Dim DataToDecrypt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Message)
        Dim Decryptor As ICryptoTransform = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor()
        Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length)
        Return UTF8.GetString(Results)
    End Function
```

I am having a hard time encrypting the data to query the SQL server.

When using EncryptString with the following parameters:

> Message = stack-overflow
>
> Passphrase = Danielle

I get:

> 1c2wL+guV34oyVS0vkxwVA==

I need to do this encryption and decryption with node.js

I tried this but it did not work:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');



encrypt(text, paraphrase) {
        const key =text;
        const secret =paraphrase;

        // Encryption
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-192-ecb", Buffer.from(key, "base64"), null);
        const encryptedSecret = cipher.update(secret, "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64");
        return(encryptedSecret);

    
    };
```

I also tried installing MD5 by npm but I had no luck either.

Any help to encrypt and decrypt will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: The VB code uses TripleDES, the NodeJS code AES-192. For compatibility, the NodeJS code must also apply TripleDES (although AES is more modern). Note that ECB is an insecure mode.

Comment: Also the key derivation with MD5 is missing in the NodeJS code (by the way also insecure, MD5 is broken; better is a key derivation via a reliable key derivation function like PBKDF2).

Comment: You can find a full running example for TDES in **unsecure** ECB mode here (disclaimer I'm the author) https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/docs/tdes_ecb_string_encryption.md [except for **unsecure** MD5 key derivation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the NodeJS code to be compatible with the VB code, TripleDES must be used instead of AES. The key must be derived with MD5. Since MD5 provides a 16 bytes key, TripleDES is applied in the double-length key variant ([2TDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options)), which combines two DES keys K1 and K2 to a TripleDES key K1|K2|K1. One possible implementation is:

```js
var key16 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(passphrase).digest();
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("des-ede-ecb", key16, null);
var ciphertext = cipher.update(data, "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64");
```

If `des-ede-ecb` is not supported, `des-ede3-ecb` can be used as an alternative. This implements TripleDES in the triple-length key variant ([3TDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options)), which combines three DES keys K1, K2 and K3 to a TripleDES key K1|K2|K3. For K3 = K1 this is equivalent to 2TDEA:

```js
var key16 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(passphrase).digest();
var key24 = Buffer.concat([key16, key16.slice(0, 8)]);
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("des-ede3-ecb", key24, null);
```

Note that ECB is insecure (better a mode with an IV like GCM), as is key derivation via a cryptographic hash function (better a reliable key derivation function like PBKDF2) and the broken MD5 as such (better SHA256). TripleDES is deprecated and slow (better AES).

###### Edit:

The decryption is completely analog, e.g. for 2TDEA:

```js
var key16 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(passphrase).digest();
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("des-ede-ecb", key16, null);
var decrypted = decipher.update(ciphertext, "base64", "utf8") + decipher.final("utf8");
```

Comment: Topaco, Im using your first code example. Can you guide me thru the decryption function? Thanks.

Comment: I see, on the third line, I was using (text, "utf8", "base64") instead of (text, "base64", "utf8") -reversed- for decrypting, and that what wasn't working for me. Thanks a lot, again Topaco!